# Search using a partial string but save the full string as a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a text file which has the following data:

```
“set current_day=24”
“set current_month=12”
“set current_year=2023”
```

The numbers can change so I have set 3 variables which will always be present:

```
day=current_day=
month=current_month=
year=current_year=
```

I can use these variables in a grep which returns the full string. I now want to save the full string as var1 so when I echo the variable I see:

```
current_day=24
```

I want the current string as a variable because the next step is for the user to enter the new ‘number’. This will create a new variable in the format of ‘current_day=10’ which will then replace ‘current_day=24’ with ‘current_day=10’.

I’ll then want to validate that the number does not have leading zeros (or just remove any prior to setting the variable.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This does not seem the correct approach. Are you perhaps looking for `declare -p current_day` instead of `echo $current_day`?

Comment: Either of awk or sed should be more than capable of this. Variable expansion may also be able to help replace the value, but I'm not 100% sure as it's been a while. If you have a script started please share the code, how it's being run, and the error. Also, checkout [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for linting, and [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/) or an alternative AI for explanation of any code you don't fully understand. [Pure Bash Bible](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible) may also be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, `sed` to achieve what you want.

If you save the new day as `new_day`, then you can run:

```bash
sed -r "s|(current_day=)[[:digit:]]*|\1$((new_day))|g" file.txt
```

`$((...))` is the [bash arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html). Therefore, it would remove any leading zeros from the `new_day` variable.

You can run the same function with `current_month` and `current_year` too:

```bash
sed -r "s|(current_month=)[[:digit:]]*|\1$((new_month))|g" file.txt
sed -r "s|(current_year=)[[:digit:]]*|\1$((new_year))|g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set variables within variables, which is... awkward and weird. If it's possible for you to make the .txt file into shell syntax, that would make things neat:

```
current_day=24
current_month=12
current_year=2023
```

Then you could source it...
`source myfile.txt`

if you want to echo the current_day...

`echo current_day=$current_day`

Then if you want to read from the user a new value into current_day...

```
echo "enter new current day"
read day
current_day=$(echo $day | sed 's/^0*//')
```

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.. I cheated and decided to truncate the file and replace everything with new values.. just couldn't get sed to work :(

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `"set var=value"`, simply set the variable `var=value` quoting as required. If you are reading a new date and want to save the current value, then just use `current_day=$day`.

If you are wanting the user to enter a new day, then there isn't really a need to save the current, instead, properly require the user enter a valid day before your script proceeds. You do that by continually looping prompting for input and then checking what the user has entered and then only exiting the *read-loop* if the user has entered a valid day.

To determine if a valid day has been entered, you need to:

1. Remove any leading zeros from the input,
2. Verify the input is an integer,
3. Verify the value is `1` to `31` (you can check each month if you like)

When the input passes all three tests, you have a good `day` and simply exit the *read-loop* at that point.

In your case for reading a new `day` value that may have leading zeros, in bash you can take advantage of `[[ str =~ regex ]]` using `(...)` to capture digits beginning with a `1` and discarding leading zeros as part of the regular expression. The captured digits are placed in the system array as the 2nd element (the first element holds the entire regex matched). That captured digits will be in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`.

For example, putting a short script together to change `day`, you can do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

day="${1:-24}"      ## get day as 1st parameter (24 default if none provided)
month="${2:-12}"    ## get month (12 default)
year="${3:-2023}"   ## get year (2023 default)

## output current date
printf "Current date (dd/mm/yyyy): %s/%s/%s\n" "$day" "$month" "$year"

## loop continually until valid day entered (1-31)
while :
do
  ## prompt for input
  printf "\nEnter new day: "
  
  ## read day
  read -r day
  
  ## check and remove leading zeros (if any)
  if [[ $day =~ ^[0]+([1-9][0-9]*).*$ ]]; then
    day="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
  
  ## check "$day" is valid integer (you can just check length here)
  if ! [[ $day =~ ^[+-]*[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    printf "error: invalid integer '%s'.\n" "$day" >&2
    continue
  fi
  
  ## check "$day" between 1-31 (adjust as needed)
  if [ 1 -le "$day" ] && [ "$day" -le 31 ]; then
    break;
  fi
  
  printf "error: invalid day entered, (1-31 only)\n" >&2
done

## output current date
printf "\nCurrent date (dd/mm/yyyy): %s/%s/%s\n\n" "$day" "$month" "$year"
```

**Note:** The script will take `day`, `month`, `year` and command line parameters to set the initial date in `dd mm yyyy` format. If no parameters are entered, the date is taken as your provided `24/12/2023` by default.

Also note the script simply discards any additional characters after a valid integer is input regardless of leading zeros. So with input of `0000010frogs`, the script would capture `10` as the integer and discard the rest.

**Example Use/Output**

Changing the day to `10` with *intentionally-wrong* inputs provided before a valid input with leading zeros, you can see how things work:

```
$ ./set-new-day.sh
Current date (dd/mm/yyyy): 24/12/2023

Enter new day: my dog has fleas!
error: invalid integer 'my dog has fleas!'.

Enter new day: -1
error: invalid day entered, (1-31 only)

Enter new day: 32
error: invalid day entered, (1-31 only)

Enter new day: 0000010

Current date (dd/mm/yyyy): 10/12/2023
```

(**note:** you can add as many more tests to the *read-loop* as you like to cover your situation, the script just covers what seemed like a minimum based on your question)

Above, no matter how many leading zeros are entered, they will be removed. Let me know if you have questions.